# Android App Crashes onPause

Tags: android, crash, onpause

I'm working on an app with ActionbarSherlock and Fragments (not sure if relevant).

I'm getting an app crash for the MainActivity onPause() and I don't know why...

This is the LogCat error for when this happens:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to pause activity {com.example.myapp/com.example.myapp.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2354)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2311)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handlePauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2291)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:117)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:938)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.saveFragmentBasicState(FragmentManager.java:1576)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.saveAllState(FragmentManager.java:1617)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onSaveInstanceState(FragmentActivity.java:481)
    at com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity.onSaveInstanceState(SherlockFragmentActivity.java:127)
    at com.example.myapp.MainActivity.onSaveInstanceState(MainActivity.java:80)
    at android.app.Activity.performSaveInstanceState(Activity.java:1037)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnSaveInstanceState(Instrumentation.java:1181)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2336)
```

My activity has implemented the default onPause method (And other methods, at request)

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}
```

I think it might be related to ActionbarSherlock cause the error messages go that way.
Any light you can throw, would be appreciated. I'm stuck.

Comment: What are you doing in onSaveInstanceState? Your crash originates from there it seems. Are you putting a null value for a key maybe?

Comment: Question updated with the relevant methods. Thanks dymmeh.

Comment: I solved it: Apparently it had to do with the inflater:
View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_list, container, false);